# Array variable type in C++ recursion is not working

Tags: c++, variables, recursion, types, eclipse-cdt

I'm starting to study recursion in C++ and I'm facing a problem that I can't figure out.

What's happening is that Eclipse and g++ are saying that my variable type is not matching with the function declaration but I believe it does.

Please take a look, first at the screen dump from Eclipse, showing the error:

[image]

And also the code in textual rather than graphical form:

```
int saida(char **matriz, char dir,int entrada_l, int entrada_c,int* zeros,int** tracker) {

    int flag3,flag4,tamanho_martiz = 8;

    int resp;
    if(dir == 'c'){
        if(matriz[entrada_l++][entrada_c] == '0'){
            resp = saida(matriz, 'c',entrada_l,entrada_c,&zeros,tracker);
        }
    }

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Post code instead.

Comment: Indexer (re-)build problems??

Comment: Sorry for post an image , i did it just to show what and how eclipse are showing the error

Comment: Added the code in text format, keeping the image since it shows the error from Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

You pass the *address* of `zeros` in your recursive call:

```
resp = salida (matrix, 'c', entrada_l, entrada_c, &zeros, tracker);
//                                                ^
```

That's an extra level of indirection from what it expects, an `int *`, while *you're* giving it an `int **`.

Get rid of the `&` in the call and that should fix the problem.